# Hide arrows from indentation and highlighting PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

How can I hide `those arrows` next to line numbers ?

And also how can I disable `the highlighting` of the current line ?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> How can I hide those arrows next to line numbers ?

I see no arrows.

You must be talking about code folding controls. If so -- `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Code Folding | Show code folding outline`

> And also how can I disable the highlighting of the current line ?

Edit your color schema and change the colors to desired ones (e.g. remove any colors) at `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Editor | Caret Row`.

NOTE: you cannot edit bundled color schema -- first create your own (`Save As...` button) and only then you can edit it.